# Create JSON String Array from Java List

Tags: java, json

I have a java.util.List containing Java POJOs that I want to render as JSON Array String. For example:

```
[
  { "name": "abc", "age": 50 },
  { "name": "def", "age": "25" }
];
```

Using Java EE JSON Api I have added:

```
public String createJsonArrayFromList(List<Person> list) {
    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    for(Person c : list) {
        jsonArray.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("name", c.getName())
                .add("surname", c.getSurname()));
    }
    JsonArray array =jsonArray.build();
    return array.toString();
}
```

However, what is returned is not the JSON String array but `"org.glassfish.json.JsonArrayBuilderImpl@761c5d2f"`

I have attemped with:

```
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
Json.createWriter(buffer).writeObject(array);
```

But writeObject expects a different object type rather than JsonArray.
Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `writeArray` instead of `writeObject`:

```java
JsonArray arr = ...;
JsonWriter writer = Json.createWriter(...)
writer.writeArray(arr);
writer.close();
```

See [the docs](https://static.javadoc.io/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.1.4/javax/json/JsonArray.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gson Library which helps you better.

```
GsonBuilder builder=new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson=builder.create();
List<YourMeberClas> YourList=new ArrayList<>();
JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(YourList, new 
TypeToken<List<YourMemberClass>>() {
            }.getType());
```

With this you can easily access the data as well.